# shell_exec in ubuntu for create scheme is slow

Tags: ubuntu, doctrine, symfony

i use

`shell_exec("./bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test");`

in Symfony  and ubuntu and MySql.
it take to long and so slow ,when i use these cod in apple pc it is too fast

i try

```
kill mysqladmin kill other process
```

but it is not good

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `./bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=prod` first of all. I don't see why you would pick test environment over dev, that one is dedicated to functional testing. Going to prod you will have a small performance boost.

But that, please post more details. It is hard to guess anything else. Is your server good enough if you run some commands over MySQL shell? Is your cache cold when you run this command? You can (should) warm up cache before, for the environment you use, such as `./bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod`.

Comment: i want to run behat test in symfony,then i want to create schema first of all,and  run "./bin/console doctrine:schema:create --env=test" in testing

Comment: is your test DB different than your prod DB? Then it would be a legitimate use case, indeed.  
Can you please check with warming up teh cache before, with ./bin/console cache:warmup --env=test ? A first request (or command) on any environment is slow on a cold cache.

Comment: i do it ,but it dose not fix problem

Comment: Can you please answer all the questions? It is hard to help you if you don't want to give information.